# background screen splits when using linear gradient css html

Tags: php, html, css

Hi we are working on a uni project. i am having a problem with the design. we have to use linear gradient as requirement from the client. it works fine on normal pages but when i use it in a page where i use a "form to submit data into a table" the screen splits into multiple portions. sometimes in 2 sometimes more.

here is the problem image
[the problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eymai.png)

It should be seem less like other pages background

like this [should be like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSOUH.png)

Here is my css code

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body,ol,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,th,td,dl,dd,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,select{background-color:none; list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
body {background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #86090F 0%, #EA3C22 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-family:Roboto,sans-serif; font-weight:300;}
a{display:block; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
img{border:none; vertical-align:middle;}
.clear{overflow:hidden; display:block; height:0; font-size:0; line-height:0; clear:both;}
.fl{float:left;width:100%;}
.fr{float:right;width:100%;}


.logout{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 6%;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #63513D;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  float:left;

  margin-top: 15px;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 15%;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #63513D;
  background-color: #D6D2C2;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
 
}

.button:hover {background-color: #EAE8E0;}

.button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}   



.container{
         width:70%;
   margin:0 auto; 
   font-size: 150%;
   
        }
header{      
            width:100%;
   margin:0 auto;
   height:85px;
   border-bottom:2px solid #404040;
   background-color:rgb(245, 242, 228);
      }
   b
.img{
    width:150px;
    border-right:1px solid #333;
    height:85px;
    margin-left:2%;
   }

   
.content1{ width:50%;
   height:20%;
 
font-size: 20px;
   text-align: left;
           margin:0 auto;
    }
    
.content1 h3{ 
              font: blone 14px Arial;
     text-align:center;
     margin-left:5px;
     }
.content1 table{
              width:100%;
     
     border-bottom:1px solid #999;
     border-right:1px solid #999;
     border-left:none;
     border-top:none;
     margin-top:10px;
     margin-left:5px;
     background-color: rgb(245, 242, 228);
     }
.content1 table td{
              width:200px;
     text-align:left;
     border-left:1px solid #999;
                 border-top:1px solid #999;
     border-right:none;
     border-bottom:none;
     height:25px;
     font: 20px Impact, Arial;
         line-height: 95%;

                  }
.content1 table tr{
                   border:none;
       
      
                  }
.box{
  width:1050px;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:15px;
  }
.content2{ 
           width:490px; 
           float:left;
    
     
     }
.content2 h3{ 
              font:blone 14px Arial;
     text-align: center;
     }
.lyb_box{ 
         width:100%;
   margin-top:15px; 
   height:400px;
   border:1px solid #000;
   margin-left:1px;
   background-color: rgb(245, 242, 228); 
   }
.lyb_box_nr{ 
           float:left;
     width:90%;
     margin-top:20px;
     }
.lyb_box_nr p{ 
            font:normal 14px Arial;
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   margin-left:7px;
   
   
        }
.lyb_box_nr input{ 
                 width:100%;
     float:left;
     margin-left:10px;
     height:30px;
     border:1px solid #CCC;
                   }
.lyb_box_nr select{ 
                 width:100%;
     float:left;
     margin-left:20px;
     height:30px;
     border:1px solid #CCC;
                   }
article{
     width:40%;
  border:2px solid #404040;
  float:right;
       }

.search{
   float:left;
   width:150px; 
   border-radius:3px; 
   margin-top:20px;
   color:#000; 
   text-align:center; 
   height:25px; 
   margin-left:330px;
   }
   
.content3{ 
           float:right;
     width:500px;
     height:400px;
     border:1px solid #404040;
     margin-top:31px;
      
           
}
.content4{ 
           float:center;
     width:500px;
     height:400px;
     border:1px solid #404040;
     margin-left:700px;
      
           
     }
     
#nav{
 color: red;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 2.8;
 word-spacing: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: -50px auto;
    height: 46px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #adadad;
 margin-right:0px;
 
    
}
#nav a{
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    height: 46px;
    line-height: 40px;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #adadad;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
 
}
#nav a:active{
 color:green;
    background-color: white;
 }

#nav a:hover{
    border-bottom: 4px solid red;
    color: red;
}


footer{
    clear: both;
font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 25px;
color: #86090F;  
    margin: 0 px auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
 background-color:#2D251A
 
}
#footer a:hover{text-decoration:underline;background-color:withe;}
#footer a, #footer a:visited {color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}
#legal {background-color:white; clear:both; list-style-type:none; overflow:hidden; padding:20px 120px 20px 24px;} 
li.first {padding-left:45%;}
li:not(#flag) {float:left; padding-right:25px;list-style-type:none;}

#k{
        padding-left:40%;
     width:500px;
     height:400px;
     border:0 px solid #404040;
     margin-top:-10px;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<? include("header.html"); ?>
</head>

<body>

    <h4><?php echo $e; ?><h4>
                
                <div>
                    <form name="form1" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <section class="content1">
     <table border="1">
                        
      <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label>
                                    User Name</label>
                          </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="username" style="width:200px;" required />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
      <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label>
                                    Password</label>
                          </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="password" style="width:200px;" required />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
      <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label>
                                    Name</label>
                          </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="name" style="width:200px;" required />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                    
<tr>
                            <td>
                                <label>
                                    Email</label>
                          </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="email" style="width:200px;" required />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
      
     
     
     
      
      <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label>
                                    Campus</label>
                          </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="campus" style="width:200px;" required />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
      
      <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label>
                              </label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
      
                     </table>
     </section>
     
                    </form>
     <div clear="both"></div>
     <a href="index.php" class="button">Back to management</a><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

i am really stuck in this problem from a long time. what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it because your body does not stretch to full height.

it stretch until the 'Back to Management' button only.

Adding this should get you what you want.

```
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/mENqNE

Comment: i added this line but its not working body {background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #86090F 0%, #EA3C22 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-family:Roboto,sans-serif; font-weight:300;  min-height: 100%;

Comment: @Gurminder add it to your html too ? `html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}`

Comment: i added like this in main html page    <body min-height="100%">  but it not works

Comment: `html, body { min-height: 100%; }` is css, not HTML attribute. It's supposed to be added into your css code.